# Log API requests via Varnish cache

Tags: php, varnish

I have Varnish in front of a standard REST API. Requests must be authenticated with an X-Access-Token header. I now need to keep track of the requests for each resource against the access token that was used. For instance, token abcd1234 requested /items/xyz 10 times.

Initially I was just going to count the data in the backend application (PHP), but then realised Varnish would of course intercept any requests after the first.

What would be the best way of tracking requests against tokens?

At the moment I'm looking at either reading varnishlog/varnishncsa in a separate thread, or adding something like the Redis VMOD and having it increment a counter based on token:url.

Has anyone done anything else like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion there are three reasonable options here:

1. Using [Varnish Custom Statistics](https://www.varnish-software.com/product/varnish-custom-statistics). VCS is part of [Varnish Plus](https://www.varnish-software.com/what-is-varnish-plus) and it has been specifically designed to solve use cases like the one you're describing. If you're using Varnish Plus this is the way to go.
2. Using varnishog / varnishncsa together with some script dumping counters to some external database.
3. Using a Redis or Memcached VMOD. Compared with option (2) this will add some negligible overhead to each request, but you will save some I/O and you can avoid implementing/maintaining the script. I think this is the best alternative if VCS cannot be used.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you to let varnish does what it does best, caching, and let the tracking done by varnishog/ncsa

By adding the Redis Vmod, you will add complexity in your vcl and if for some reasons your redis goes down, you will loose your tracking.

Using varnishlog/ncsa, you can build your tracking logic outside varnish, process the log in realtime by piping the varnishlog process or store the log for a latter use.